# Limit the permission queryset on Django's Group model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to limit the permissions that are available to be assigned to groups in the Django admin interface to certain apps. Something like this:

```
# not working
Group.permissions.limit_choices_to = {"content_type__app_label": "project"}
```

So far I couldn't find a way to modify the m2m field, it always shows all Permission records.